# C# mongodb - how to update nested array elements

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the following JSON structure that represents an item

```
{
    Id: "a",
    Array1: [{
        Id: "b",
        Array2: [{
            Id: "c",
            Array3: [
                {...}
            ]
        }]
    }]
}
```

I need to be able to either replace the array element in `Array2` with a new item or to replace just `Array3` with a new array.

Here is my code to replace the array item in `Array2`:

```
await Collection.UpdateOneAsync(
    item => item.Id.Equals("a") &&
    item.Array1.Any(a => a.Id.Equals("b")) &&
    item.Array1[-1].Array2.Any(b => b.Id.Equals("c")),
    Builders<Item>.Update.Set(s => s.Array1[-1].Array2[-1], newArray2Item)
);
```

When executing this code I'm getting this error:

```
"A write operation resulted in an error.
 Too many positional (i.e. '$') elements found in path 'Array1.$.Array2.$'"
```

Here is my code to replace `Array3` within `Array2`:

```
await Collection.UpdateOneAsync(
        item => item.Id.Equals("a") &&
        item.Array1.Any(a => a.Id.Equals("b")) &&
        item.Array1[-1].Array2.Any(b => b.Id.Equals("c")),
        Builders<Item>.Update.Set(s => s.Array1[-1].Array2[-1].Array3, newArray3)
    );
```

And this is the error:

```
"A write operation resulted in an error.
 Too many positional (i.e. '$') elements found in path 'Array1.$.Array2.$.Array3'"
```

I'm using C# MongoDB driver version 2.5.0 and MongoDB version 3.6.1

I found this Jira ticket [Positional Operator Matching Nested Arrays](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831) that says the problem was fixed and they suggested this syntax for the update

```
Update all matching documents in nested array:

db.coll.update({}, {$set: {“a.$[i].c.$[j].d”: 2}}, {arrayFilters: [{“i.b”: 0}, {“j.d”: 0}]})
Input: {a: [{b: 0, c: [{d: 0}, {d: 1}]}, {b: 1, c: [{d: 0}, {d: 1}]}]}
Output: {a: [{b: 0, c: [{d: 2}, {d: 1}]}, {b: 1, c: [{d: 0}, {d: 1}]}]}
```

So I converted it to my elements:

```
db.getCollection('Items').update(
{"Id": "a"},
{$set: {"Array1.$[i].Array2.$[j].Array3": [newArray3]}}, 
{arrayFilters: 
    [
        {"i.Id": "b"}, 
        {"j.Id": "c"}
    ]}
)
```

And got this error:

```
cannot use the part (Array1 of Array.$[i].Array2.$[j].Array3) to traverse the element
```

Any ideas on how to solve this error?

Comment: It's not pretty but as a shortcut you can always just write your updates using strings like you'd write them in the shell and then pass them to the `Update()` method.

Comment: This is why I gave the sample from Jira. It still doesn't work,,,

Comment: You will need an updated client for this to work (try the "mongo.exe" shell that came with your distribution): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47225822/mongodb-3-6-0-rc3-array-filters-not-working

Comment: I can't use `mongo.exe` in C#... the link you sent me is talking about robomongo.

Comment: I know. ;) The last query you gave in your example is a string based one that you should be able to run inside mongo.exe without getting an error. That's all I'm saying. Once you've got that query working you can use the filter and update parts of it to create a C# version.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/setFeatureCompatibilityVersion/#view-fcv) and [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/setFeatureCompatibilityVersion/#dbcmd.setFeatureCompatibilityVersion) to run it I only needed to run this command `db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.6" } )`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the C# version of what you need:

```
var filter = Builders<Item>.Filter.Eq("Id", "a");
var update = Builders<Item>.Update.Set("Array1.$[i].Array2.$[j].Array3", new[] { new Item { Id = "d" } });
var arrayFilters = new List<ArrayFilterDefinition> { new JsonArrayFilterDefinition<Item>("{'i.Id': 'b'}"), new JsonArrayFilterDefinition<Item>("{'j.Id': 'c'}") };
var updateOptions = new UpdateOptions { ArrayFilters = arrayFilters };
collection.UpdateOne(filter, update, updateOptions);
```

Comment: It doesn't work from C# but does work from `Studio 3T` any idea why? It doesn't give an error and looks like the command went through, but the update does not apply...

Comment: The only difference I see is that I use the filters for the `id` like this: `"_id", "ObjectId(ITEM_ID)"` and like this: "{\"i._id\": ObjectId(ARRAY_ITEM_ID)}" because  the id's are generated by mongo and represented by `ObjectId`. Any suggenstions?

Comment: I would suggest you log your queries (`db.setProfilingLevel(2)`) and check the MongoDB log file for what the resulting query looks like when you run your C# code. That alone is likely to reveal the problem, I guess. Otherwise you could run that resulting query in Studio3T and see if it produces the right result there (it won't) and why it does not.

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/mongodb-where-is-the-log-file/ description for Linux but also pretty much applicable for Windows.

Comment: I found some log file under `C:\data\log\mongod.log`, but it doesn't write anything to it... I couldn't find anything that looks like `/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log`

Comment: Fount it, it was under `C:\data\log\mongod.log` but I also needed to `db.setLogLevel(5)` [SetLogLevel](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.setLogLevel/)

Comment: Now it works, turns out I needed to set the id like this `var filter = Builders<Setup>.Filter.Eq("_id", new ObjectId(configurationDevice.SetupId));`

Comment: Thank you for the help. Much appreciated :-)

Comment: You're welcome and, yes, that sounds very correct. My example was based on your sample JSON above. But when dealing with string based queries, the C# driver won't translate any property names.

Comment: Can you please try and help me out with another question on how to remove items? posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48887667/c-sharp-mongodb-how-to-remove-an-item-from-multiple-nested-arrays-by-element-v)