# How to update element in set in MongoDB?

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-web-api, bson

I have example entry in my database:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6241d974a7382732093700d1"
  },
  "userdata": {
    "Name": "SomeName",
    "Surname": "SomeSurname",
    "Email": "someEmail@gmail.com",
    "Adress": {
      "Ulica": "Street",
      "NumerDomu": "2137",
      "NumerMieszkania": "2137",
      "KodPocztowy": "22222",
      "Miasto": "Warsaw"
    }
  },
  "username": "usrnmatest",
  "password": "$2a$11$kLDNbOmg2Ju4jl4o7mcyyuThuE5ZN1xd4VB10TYI/xPtQO.zM828a",
  "cards": [
    {
      "issuer": "Visa",
      "cardNumber": "46556456445564",
      "expiryMonth": "12",
      "expiryYear": "2027",
      "CVV": "223",
      "name": "Pablo",
      "address": "Krynica 21",
      "country": "Poland",
      "zipcode": "33-380"
    },
    {
      "issuer": "MasterCard",
      "cardNumber": "2178811445564",
      "expiryMonth": "10",
      "expiryYear": "2032",
      "CVV": "114",
      "name": "Some Data",
      "address": "ul.Moskiewskiego 21",
      "country": "Poland",
      "zipcode": "33-380"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to update, for example `card` by it's `cardNumber`.
I wrote something like this:

```
var arrayFilter = Builders<User>.Filter.Eq("Id", user.Id)
                & Builders<User>.Filter.Eq("cardNumber", card.cardNumber);
            var arrayUpdate = Builders<User>.Update.Set("cards.$", card);
            var res = _userCollection.UpdateOne(arrayFilter, arrayUpdate);
```

But I'm getting `0` modified fields.

I kind of followed this tutorial [Tutorial Link](https://jacekstyrylski.github.io/2018/02/01/MongoDB-Update-array-element-net/)
Any idea how to make it work?

Also here is my model of `User`:

```
    public class User
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string? Id { get; set; }

        [BsonRequired]
        [BsonElement("userdata")]
        [Required]
        public UserData? DaneUzytkownika { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("username")]
        [BsonRequired]
        [Required]
        public string UserName { get; set; } = null!;

        [BsonElement("password")]
        [BsonRequired]
        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; } = null!;

        [BsonElement("cards")]
        public List<Card>? cards { get; set; }

    }
```

And my `Card` model if this can help:

```
    public class Card
    {
        public string? issuer { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("cardNumber")]
        public string? cardNumber { get; set; }

        public string? expiryMonth { get; set; }

        public string? expiryYear { get; set; }

        public string? CVV { get; set; }

        public string? name { get; set; }

        public string? address { get; set; }

        public string? country { get; set; }

        public string? zipcode { get; set; }


    }
```

Comment: this maybe of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48180188/c-sharp-mongodb-update-an-element-inside-a-nested-document

Comment: Should `"Id"` be `"_id"` in your filter? Admittedly, I'm not sure, it's been a few months since I used MDB .NET driver.

Comment: Guess MBD Driver just translate it because I have simillar method above in this controller that works with "Id"

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the order of elements in your update query , the correct is:

```
 UpdateOne(filter, update, updateOptions)
```

and the arrayFilters usually is located in the updateOptions:

```
db.collection.update({
  // here filter the document that need to be updated
 {
   "_id": {
    "$oid": "6241d974a7382732093700d1"
   }
 },
{
 // here change the necessary values inside the cards array element
 $set: {
   "cards.$[x].CVV": "Something in the cards that need to be updated"
}
},
{
 // and this is where you define the arrayFilters 
  arrayFilters: [
   {
     "x.cardNumber": "46556456445564"
   }
  ]
 })
```

[example playground via JS mongo shell](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qQWhv3HJA0y)

Comment: What should I put in place of `filter` then?

Comment: Also there is still something wrong
[link](https://ibb.co/6m8fNds)

Comment: updated my answer with JS example , but must be similar for C#